# Identify Basement Plumbing Access

Tags: plumbing, basement, sewer, cleanout

I am considering finishing my basement and trying to identify the plumbing in the photos. Cutout is approximately 42" x 22" with a 1-1/2" shelf formed into the concrete where layers of wood sit to create a floor above. I know the sewer clean-out is in the upper portion of the photo, but not sure what the square valve nor the connecting pipe is. The "square valve" connects to another pipe that appears to have an open top (like a drain?) also filled with standing water. This access has been covered as long as we've live in the house and never caused a problem, and the standing water has been there as well.

I plan on replacing the existing wood slats with 5/4 PT decking and then another 1/2" layer of some substrate on top to level it off (maybe concrete board or 1/2" PT plywood - still undecided).

FYI the piece of clay pipe on the left appears to be leftover - not connected to anything, just laying there.

Can anyone shed some light on what's happening here?

[image: Basement plumbing cut-out]

[image: Basement plumbing cut-out 2]

Comment: That standing water is not doing the pipes or you any favours.  Any work/removing covers will probably result in replacement of the pipes.  Just wondering if the smaller pipe is your main water inlet/valve?

Comment: The main water line is on the opposite side of the basement.